# Tukey HSD for three-way interaction term in R

Tags: r, anova, interaction, posthoc, tukey

For each dependent variable (time, mass, rate, quotient), I constructed a `three-way ANOVA` with gender, age, temperature and all interactions as the independent fixed factors.

> My outputs range from getting a significant two-way interaction term
>   to a significant three-way interaction term.

How can I do `post hoc comparison` using `Tukey's HSD` in `R` for these (two-way and three-way) interaction term ?

Thank you.